# Feature Receiver: Add users from list to a group

Tags: development

I have a list 'Users' with a column 'UsersToAdd' of Type "Person or Group" which I like to use for provisioning a SP group 'MyUsers' at the creating of a new site. 
I have created a feature receiver for this in my Custom Web Template.

When trying to deploy the feature I get an error on the SPFieldUserValue element:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Does anyone have an idea how to refactor this code for use in a Feature receiver? 
(It works when using it as code behind in a Custom App Page)

```
int ListID; //ID of item containing the users

string listUrl = string.Format("{0}/Lists/Users", sweb.Url);

SPList list = sweb.GetList(listUrl);
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(ListID);
SPFieldUserValueCollection Users = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item["UsersToAdd"];

cweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
foreach (SPFieldUserValue fuv in Users)
{
cweb.EnsureUser(@fuv.User.LoginName);
cweb.SiteGroups[MyUsers].AddUser(@fuv.User.LoginName, string.Empty, fuv.LookupValue, string.Empty);
}

cweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Comment: Is the third line really right? You're getting the item using the ListID? IF it isn't, that could be your problem.

What populates ListID?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that ListID is and int defined above.
So the correct item is used...
Problem is at line foreach (SPFieldUserValue fuv in Users)
Seams Feature Receiver has issues with object SPFieldUserValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code as far as I can see. Therefor I tested your code and the time I get the error you described is when the field "UsersToAdd" in the list is empty(doesn't contain any value).
A check for null on "Users" will prevent you from getting the error.

Regards, Anita

Comment: Hi Anita,
Thanks for your update on this... I'm going to do some more debugging today taking your remarks into account!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I reckon the third line should be:

```
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(ListItemID);
```

Also, note that you can attach Visual Studio to the W3WP process for debugging - I find that very useful in event handlers.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that ListID is and int defined above. So the correct item is used... Problem is at line foreach (SPFieldUserValue fuv in Users) Seams Feature Receiver has issues with object SPFieldUserValue

Comment: Do you have a SharePoint group in one of the fields? I'm not sure that they'd have a LoginName - or even a User object.

Comment: No SharePoint Groups are passed, only single users... Just to make sure the code works fine as code behind of a Custom App Page, it only throws an error in VS2010 when I try to use it in my feature Receiver code... Mainly the use of SPFieldUserValue.. Following post does it in a slightly diffrent way (also feature receiver code)   http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/08/automatically-setting-custom.html